# jQuery preload images from list

Tags: jquery, image-preloader

I want to preload rollover images in jQuery but the list of images is inside list of like this:

```
<li><a href="/images/1.jpg"></a></li>
<li><a href="/images/2.jpg"></a></li>
<li><a href="/images/3.jpg"></a></li>
```

==========

```
function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    });
}

var imagelist = $('li a').attr("href");
preload(imagelist);
```

I changed the last line so it just grab the href from my list.  Original script was from: [Preloading images with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery)

Is this correct?

Comment: Your var imagelist is only going to contain the href of the first 'li a' it finds.

Comment: Can someone suggest a way to test preloading images (especially on local server since images load so fast anyway)?  Something in firebug I can use?

Comment: @David in Firebug, click the "net" tab and then "images" and watch the requests.

Comment: Thanks for the firebug tip David.

Comment: NP, please accept an answer below that you think answered your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$.map` to convert the nodeList into an array of hrefs:

```
var imageList = $('li a').map(function() {
    return this.href;
});

preload(imageList);
```

Or skip the preload function and do a simple loop instead:

```
$('li a').each(function() {
    (new Image).src = this.href;
});
```

If you want to use it as a plugin try:

```
$.fn.preload = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        (new Image).src = this.href;
    });
};

$('li a').preload();
```

Comment: The resulting imageList is an object; does that matter to the preload function, or does JS's loose typing just handle it?

Comment: Arrays are objects in Javascript. And the $.each method in jQuery handles both.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
var imagelist = $('li a').each(function() {
    preload($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

**Or** you can do this:

```
$.fn.preload = function() {
    this.each(function(){
        //alert("preloading " + $(this).attr("href"));
        $('<img/>')[0].src = $(this).attr("href");
    });
}
$('li a').preload();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hbvM8/)

Comment: But make sure you change preload so it accepts only a single href, not an array. (`function preload(input){$('<img/>')[0].src = input;}`)

Comment: @pinouchon.  Thanks.  Can I just do this?
    $(li a).each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = $this.attr("href");
    });

Comment: @David Yes you can. Just fix some syntax errors. [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/d8cLZ/)

Comment: @pinouchon: Maybe you don't have to, but it seems a lot clearer and probably a little more efficient to me.

Comment: @someone it depends... If you already use the preload function elsewhere, it's better not to change it.

Comment: ``$('<img/>')[0].src = $(this).attr("href");`` can be rewritten to ``(new Image).src = this.href``

Answer (score 0):

You can populate your imagelist like this to make it an array:

```
var imagelist = [];
$('li a').each(function(){
  imagelist.push($(this).attr('href'));
})
```